# I have problems with the syntax in C. I'm not so sure about the pointers and the arrays in my programm

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-errors, function-definition, pointer-arithmetic

This is the program I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double squareVec(double vec[], int n) {//eckige Klammer
    int j=0;

    for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {// Inkrementierung und ; und n ausgebessert und J=0
        double*vec[j] = &vec[j] * &vec[j];
    }

    return vec;
}

int main() {//int main
    double vec[3] = {-1.0,2.0,0.0};
    int j=0;

    squareVec(vec,3);

    for(j=0; j<3; ++j) {
        printf("vec[%d] = %f ",j,vec[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I'm trying this:
The function squareVec is to square all entries of a vector.
(-1, 2, 0) is to become (1, 4, 0). The vector has to be passed as a pointer.

My problem is:

The line "double*vec[j] = &vec[j] * &vec[j];" is not correct. An array is actually a pointer right, so I don't have to write "

double*vec[j]

double vec[j] ist enough I believe but I'm not sure. Further I believe that the & in "&vec[j]" should also be left out because if I want to have as a result the number squared I don't need to do this by multiplying two adresses, I need to do this with the actual number. I'm also not so sure about the return vec. Do I even need a return function.? Doesn't it automatically go to the main function when the for loop has ended?

I tried exactly this but the compiler always puts out:
"squareVec.c:5:1: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
**double** vec[j]=vec[j]*vec[j];

Comment: Get rid of the `double*` and of the two `&` characters in the same statement.

Comment: And make up your mind on what it is that you want to return - an array or a single value. The return statement implies the former, but the function declaration implies the latter.

Comment: What does your *text-books* say? If you don't have any books, now might be a good time to invest in some.

Comment: Firtst of all thank you for your help!
I'm a programming beginner so this might sound stupid but how can you tell that the function declaration wants as return a single value? An how can you tell that the return command that I have written wants as a return an array?

Comment: You declare the function as `double squareVec(double vec[], int n)`. That means it will return a single `double` value. The variable `vec`, despite its declaration, is a pointer and have the type `double *`. And as you are modifying the array in-place there's really no need to return anything.

Comment: Thank you!
But  I don't understand why the variable "vec" is despite its declaration a pointer? Could you please explain this to me

Comment: Unless you use negative sizes to mean something special, you should use `size_t` for sizes, not `int`. Furthermore, if you rearrange your function parameters like `double squareVec(size_t n, double vec[static n])`, then that enables optimizations and allows the compiler to check that `vec` always has at least `n` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the return type of the function `double` and even `double *`  does not make sense. The return type of the function should be `void`.

There is no sense to declare the variable `j` outside the for loop and initialize it twice

```
int j=0;
for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {// Inkrementierung und ; und n ausgebessert und J=0
```

This declaration

```
double*vec[j] = &vec[j] * &vec[j];
```

is invalid. And the compiler issues the corresponding error message

> squareVec.c:5:1: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
> double vec[j]=vec[j]*vec[j];

because it  considers this line as a declaration of a variable length array with `j` elements of the type `double *`.

Instead you need to write a staement like

```
vec[j] = vec[j] * vec[j];
```

Here is your function.

```
void squareVec( double vec[], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        vec[i] = vec[i] * vec[i];
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
double vec[3] = {-1.0,2.0,0.0};
const size_t N = sizeof( vec ) / sizeof( *vec );

squareVec( vec,N );
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why the return function should be void? I thought when it's void then the a varible cannot be read or changed with the * operator. Consequently this pops into my mind : With this code line "printf("vec[%d] = %f ",j,vec[j]);", how does the compiler know where the vec[j] values are saved?

Comment: @kilston You called the function like squareVec( vec,N );. The expression vec in this call is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array vec. So using the pointer within the function and the pointer arithmetic vec[i] within the function you can change any element of the original array.